# Send dict as response in Python Bottle with custom status code

Tags: python, json, http, bottle

```
import bottle
from bottle import route, run

@route('/', method='GET')
def homepage():
    return {'foo' : 'bar'}

if __name__=='__main__':
    bottle.debug(True)
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8080, reloader = True)
```

This config will return a json object representing the dict from homepage with HTTP status code 200. What should I do to return the same content but with, say, 202 status code?

Comment: perhaps do `return str({'foo':'bar'})`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the `response.status` attribute:

```
from bottle import response

@route('/', method='GET')
def homepage():
    response.status = 202
    return {'foo' : 'bar'}
```

Comment: I've done "from bottle import response/ response.status_code = 202" and got AttributeError. What should I import considering that I'm using the global app?

Comment: Sorry, it's `status`, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: I got this: `NameError: global name 'response' is not defined`

Comment: Should have imported `response` first